# PHP 7.3 strpos() needles issue?

Tags: php, search, strpos

**ERROR:** strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior in

Having read a slew of online topics on this - none of them seem to touch on how I have code which makes me uncertain where I am wrong.

This code uses the get to search text files and returns an array of files with that search. Code worked up until the 7.3 update.

```
  $search_get = $_GET['q'];
  if ($search_get = NULL) {
  $search_get = 'encyclopedia';
  }

  foreach (glob("dir/*.txt") as $search) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($search);
    if (!strpos($contents, $search_get)) continue;
    $found[] = $search;
  }
```

How is $search_get not valid here?

Comment: You set `$search_get` TO null in the first if condition. Use `==` or `===` instead.

Comment: and this `if (!strpos($contents, $search_get))` could potentially yield false positives. use `!== false` since `0` is a valid return value. and using `!` will evaluate `0` as falsy when in fact it is possibly correct.

Comment: @PaulT. Ugh, that == thin was a simple duh I missed. Thx!

Comment: @Ghost I was having problems prior with false pos which is why I used a value to fill in the void .. this makes more sense, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@paul-t is right you are assigning the variable instead of comparing it to null, that's why you should use so-called [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

```php
if (null === $search_get) {
    $search_get = 'encyclopedia';
}
```

Anyway this is a slightly simplified version of your code:

```php
$search_get = @$_GET['q'] ?: 'encyclopedia';

foreach (glob("dir/*.txt") as $search) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($search);
    if (!empty($contents) && false !== strpos($contents, $search_get)) {
        $found[] = $search;
    }
}
```

BTW consider using `stripos` instead of `strpos`, because currently your checks on `$contents` variable are case-sensitive.

Comment: and again, to reiterate my comment above `strpos($contents, $search_get)` you cannot compare `strpos` return value loosely since `0` is a valid return value. use `!== false` if you mean _found_